# MariaDB: select all fields but one field is modified

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i am using MariaDB.  i have a table with 50 columns.  i want to create a simple query like `SELECT * FROM myTable` but the `id` column is a binary UUID which needs converting into human readable format, like this:

```sql
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(HEX(id), 1, 8), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(id), 9, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(id), 13, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(id), 17, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(id), 21)
))
FROM myTable
```

the problem is, AFAIK, i now have to explicitly name each subsequent 49 columns if i want to get them all.  now i know this is dumb, and i'm sure there is a correct way to do this but i can't find how to do what i want: simply get all 50 columns with this ONE modified SELECT.  it striked me a something that is doable, regardless of how or which column needs modifying, but i haven't been able to find such information.

if this were just mySQL, i could use the built-in commands for managing UUIDs, but MariaDB doesn't have those; they didn't make it into the last update as they'd hoped.  :P

so how can i build a query that does what i need it to do?

EDIT: for the knucklehead that flagged this with 'already answered', READ THE TITLE. I do NOT want to exclude a column, I want to MODIFY one. >_>

Comment: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful#:~:text=SELECT%20*%20exposes%20your%20system%20to,or%20present%20that%20new%20data.)

Comment: You could do: `select concat('SELECT ',group_concat(column_name),' FROM myTable') from information_schema.columns where table_name='myTable';`  and then do some copy/paste on the result.

Comment: Use `SELECT *, {expression} AS readable_UUID FROM ...`. This will give 51 columns. Then simply ignore `UUID` column on the client side. Or hide 1st column on the grid.

Comment: @Akina I didn't know you could just ADD columns after the '*'. I always thought it was only usable by itself. that's the way to go. thank you very much.